# Textbox Currency Formatting

Tags: asp.net, gridview, formatting, currency, templatefield

I am formatting a gridview templatefield that is databound with{0:c} and it displays currency as such:

```
$790.00
```

Is there a way to adjust it so the dollar symbol isn't displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to change your format specifier to 'f'.  Here's an example:

```
    double foo = 790f;
    string bar = string.Format("{0:f}", foo);
```

**Output**

> 790.00

Shame on you for not looking this up :D

See this article for details on numeric formatting:  [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, next time I'll search harder bc I looked and cldnt find anything

Answer (score 0):

```
string foo="$790"
string blahblah=foo.replace("$","");
TextBox1.Text=blahblah;
```

output=790

:)